# Python dictionary with default key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, default, default-value

I am running Python 2.7.10.

I would like to have a dictionary return the value stored at a particular key in case of missing item. For example, something like that:

```
myD = dict(...)
return myD[key] if key in myD else myD[defaultKey]
```

Just to make sure it is clear, I want to call `myD[key]` and have the right value returned without the extra `if...else` in my code...

This isn't quite what `defaultdict` does (since it takes a function to call as a default) and not quite what `dict.setdefault()` does, and `myD.get(key, ???)` does not seem to help either. I probably should inherit from `dict` or `defaultdict` and overload `__init__()` and `missing()` methods, but I could not come up with a good way to do this.

Comment: What's your question, exactly? You're right that `dict.get` won't do that; if you want to know how you could write your own, look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.MutableMapping and implement `__getitem__` accordingly. But where should `defaultKey` come from (is it a parameter? An attribute of the class, or of the instance?)

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, that's my question, how to implement this. I am not sure  how to use the ABCs in this context

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, `defaultKey` is param at initialization, that the instance should store as an attribute

Comment: You inherit them, then implement the methods they specify (in this case `__[get/set/del]item__`, `__iter__` and `__len__`, plus your custom `__init__` for the default key-value pair).

Comment: @jonrsharpe i was hoping i could get something easier by inheriting from a ready-made object, like `defaultdict`, and just overriding `__getitem__`, leaving same functionality everywhere else...

Comment: You can do it in under 20 lines, including the import, it's really not that big of a deal! If you want to try inheriting an existing class and implementing `__getitem__`, then **try doing that**; it's still not clear why you're asking the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's a lot of lines :P

Comment: @DeliriousMistakes it *really* isn't!

Comment: @jonrsharpe i was hoping there would be an already implemented class to do something like that, it seems like a very standard task to do -- and figured i am not googling something right

Comment: @gt6989b if it makes you feel better: as far as I'm aware there isn't a class in the standard library that implements what you want out of the box, so you *will* have to write this yourself. However, it's not difficult to do so, either subclassing e.g. `dict` or starting from `collections.MutableMapping`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, feel free to write out your suggestion as an answer and i will be happy to accept it

Comment: @gt6989b no, I'm not writing it for you (or, rather, not posting what I wrote to check you *could* do it easily). Go and give this a go yourself - that's how you learn! If you get stuck, then you can ask a decent question with a [mcve] and specific error message.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i did not mean to write it in code -- just copy/paste your comments in an answer so i can accept it and give you credit your advice deserves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you want (didn't read *all* the comments under your question), but think this may be at least close to what you want.

```
class DefaultKeyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, default_key, *args, **kwargs):
        self.default_key = default_key
        super(DefaultKeyDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __missing__ (self, key):
        if self.default_key not in self:  # default key not defined
            raise KeyError(key)
        return self[self.default_key]

    def __repr__(self):
        return ('{}({!r}, {})'.format(self.__class__.__name__,
                                      self.default_key,
                                      super(DefaultKeyDict, self).__repr__()))

    def __reduce__(self):  # optional, for pickle support
        args = (self.default_key if self.default_key in self else None,)
        return self.__class__, args, None, None, self.iteritems()

dkdict = DefaultKeyDict('b', {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3})

print dkdict['a']  # -> 1
print dkdict['b']  # -> 2
print dkdict['c']  # -> 3
print dkdict['d']  # -> 2 (value of the default key)

del dkdict['b']  # delete the default key
try:
    print dkdict['d']  # should now raise exception like normal
except KeyError:
    print("dkdict['d'] raised a KeyError")
```

You might want to modify the class `__init__()` method to accept both the default key and its value as arguments (instead of just the key).

Comment: thanks, i was toying with this for a while to make it work, couldn't do it right... thank you very much. If i want to pass an arg *default_key* in `__init__()` as you suggest, the signature would change to `def __init__(self, default_key, *args, **kwargs)`? Or do I just check if `default_key` is in `kwargs` (if so, how can i distinguish this from someone actually wanting a pair like this in the dictionary itself)?

Comment: For the record, the canonical sentinel (for when `None` is inappropriate due to being a valid value) is to just do `sentinel = object()` (`sentinel` can be `Null` if you like, but I find `sentinel` to describe the purpose more directly) and perform all comparisons to it with `is` (mostly for efficiency; `object`'s `__eq__` is an identity check anyway). No need to create a relatively expensive class to define the sentinel type; `object` can be constructed directly to get a unique marker using almost no resources (object inst. is a mere 16 bytes on Py 3.5, vs. 1016B+56B for class + instance).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Point taken...although I'm not overly concerned with the additional memory usage since only one instance is ever created. It's not a sentinel in the sense that it doesn't mark the beginning or end of anything, so I didn't give it that name.

Comment: @gt6989b: You could make the signature `def __init__(self, default_key, default_key_value, *args, **kwargs)` _or_ make it a keyword argument. To distinguish the latter from a user key/value pair, the keyword could start with an underscore, i.e. `_default_key=('DefaultKey', 42)`. Doing something like that is, by convention, how private names are usually designated in Python.

Answer (score 5):

In your case, `dict.get` should work(I know you already mentioned it didn't work). Did you try:

```
myD.get(key,myD[defaultKey])
```

Comment: yes, that would work, but I need to make a class that would do that by default without me specifying it explicitly in my calling code

Comment: @gt6989b so, again, *what is your question*? If it's just *"how do I write that?"* it's too broad for SO.

Comment: Have you tried creating a class that inherits `defaultdict` but overrides the `defaultfactory` method?

Comment: I agree with Robert. In that case, create your own implementation of a dictionary and override its `.get()` to the above code

Comment: The `defaultfactory` actually changes the dict to have a new thing. `get` returns a reference to an existing thing. So depending on what you want...

Answer (score 1):

When overwriting `__getitem__`, one can use simply square brackets. It returns the value for the first valid key and `None` if no key is found.

```py
class mDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, keys):
        for k in keys:
            if k in self:
                return self.get(k)

mdict = mDict({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'default': 3})

mdict['a', 'default']        # -> 1
mdict['X', 'b', 'default']   # -> 2
mdict['X', 'Y', 'default']   # -> 3
mdict['X', 'Y', 'Z']         # -> None
```

One can use here also more than just two keys, which is more readable than many nested `.get()`.

Comment: Not sure this really answers the question, though